# Design a database to store API rate limit settings for the organization/user

Tags: database-design

I am trying to implement a feature to save API rate limit/ access control settings for APIs for different organizations/users.

The scenario is:

- An organization can have multiple users.
- A user can have multiple API rate limits for the different APIs.
- Organization can be deleted hence deleting all users saved under that organization along with there settings.
- A user can be deleted with all his rate limit settings.
- User specific rate limit can be deleted.

Current table design

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS endpoints_access_control_beta 
( 
    id        uuid PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(), 
    organization TEXT, 
    UNIQUE (organization) 
-- can't have same user and organization combo! 
); 
  
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS endpoint_access_control_entry 
( 
    id                         uuid PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(), 
    user_id                    TEXT, 
    path                       TEXT NOT NULL, 
    method                     TEXT, -- may not be passed, i.e. NULL 
    api_calls_per_minute_limit NUMERIC, 
    api_calls_per_hour_limit   NUMERIC, 
    api_calls_per_day_limit    NUMERIC, 
    lock_duration_in_hours     NUMERIC, 
    endpoints_ac_id            uuid REFERENCES endpoints_access_control_beta (id), 
    UNIQUE (user_id, path, method) 
); 
  
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS endpoint_access_control_entry_path_null_method_idx 
    ON endpoint_access_control_entry (user_id, path) 
    WHERE method IS NULL; 
  
create unique index IF NOT EXISTS endpoint_access_control_entry_path_null_user_idx 
    ON endpoint_access_control_entry (path, method) 
    WHERE user_id IS NULL;
```

Based on this design the **endpoint_access_control_entry** will have repeated entries for a user in case that user has several entries hence the username being repeated in several places.

I was thinking of creating a separate table for the organization, user, and API rate limits, but feel two tables with single columns do not make sense.

What would be the most efficient and expandable design approach?